# eloquent with() in multiple where() clouse

Tags: laravel

I am trying to filter results of relationship table.

```
public function read_projects_by_coords(Request $request)
{

    $from_lat = $request->get("from_lat");
    $to_lat = $request->get('to_lat');
    $from_lng = $request->get('from_lng');
    $to_lng = $request->get('to_lng');

    $projects = Project::with(["details" => function($query) use ($from_lat, $from_lng, $to_lat, $to_lng){
        return $query->where("details.lat", ">", $from_lat)
                     ->where("details.lat", "<", $to_lat)
                     ->where("details.lng", ">", $from_lng)
                     ->where("details.lng", "<", $to_lng);
    }])->get();

    return response()->json($projects);
}
```

But when I run the above `details(child)` coming with a empty/null result **and parent/Project table not filtered. I returns all...**

For example `$projects = Project::with(["details"])->get();` this is works without a problem. But when I try to filter Project Model with the `where` inside the `with()` I can't get the `detail` object records, and parent is not filtered.

to anyone who wants to see the models parent and child

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = "projects";
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $with = ["details"];

    public function details(){
        return $this->hasOne("App\Models\Detail");
    }
}

class Detail extends Model
{
    protected $table = "details";
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Project");
    }
}
```

What am I am missing?

Comment: remove `return` from query + try to remove where one by one and check where you made mistake.

Comment: Are all the required values present in your input?

Comment: yes, checked that already, not problem with that part. And a bit misleading. I want to filter parent/Project table by the childs result... @apokryfos

Comment: I think you need `whereHas` to filter the parent by the child result. `with` will just filter the child results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter the `Project` table to only select the ones with some `Details` matching your parameters, you need to use `whereHas`. You need to keep your `with` clause too in order to have the `details` property correctly populated.

I would use a callback to not repeat the same conditions

```php
$callback = function($query) use ($from_lat, $from_lng, $to_lat, $to_lng) {
  $query->where("lat", ">", $from_lat)
    ->where("lat", "<", $to_lat)
    ->where("lng", ">", $from_lng)
    ->where("lng", "<", $to_lng);
}

$projects = Project::with(['details' => $callback])
    ->whereHas('details', $callback)
    ->get();

return response()->json($projects);
```